# does merry handle exceptions in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, merry

i was looking for more pythonic ways to handle errors in python and i found **merry**

if you never heard of it here is the documentation : https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/merry

so i wrote a little code using merry

```
from merry import Merry

merry = Merry()

@merry._try
def write_to_file(filename,data):
    with open(filename,'w') as file_obj:
        file_obj.write(data) 

@merry._except(FileNotFoundError)
def fileNotFoundError():
    print("File not found")

@merry._except(Exception)
def catch_all(e):
    print(f"exception occured :{e}")

@merry._else
def else_clause():
    print("no exceptions occured")

path = "C:/Users/User/Desktop1/dataHere.txt"
text = "top secret information"

write_to_file(path,text)
```

**note that i changed path to raise**

> FileNotFoundError

i thought merry would handle the error but instead i got this output:

> [merry] Exception caught
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\merry.py", line 26, in wrapper
>       ret = f(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/merrymerry.py", line 7, in
>   write_to_file
>       with open(filename,'w') as file_obj: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'C:/Users/j.sinjaradze/Desktop1/dataHere.txt' 
>   File not found

is there anything i did wrong or its just merry does not work as i expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood your output/how merry works. In your output you have:

```
[merry] Exception caught
```

which indicates that merry caught the exception. Then comes the traceback of the exception, which merry outputs by default, followed by

```
File not found
```

which is the result of your

```
def fileNotFoundError():
    print("File not found")
```

so it all works just fine

**Appendix**. Why does merry output the exception?

In the source code of merry (see github you linked), there is this line (merry.py:46):

```
self.logger.exception('[merry] Exception caught')
```

`self.logger` is previously created from a `logging.getLogger(logger_name)` call and the exception function prints the message provided additionally to the traceback of a previously occured exception(see [python logging documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.exception) for details).

From the source code I cannot see a way to change that behaviour without touching the source of `merry.py`

Comment: Thanks for answer ^_^ , but idon't understand why does it display traceback ?

Comment: @FlyingTeller You can access the logger (https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/merry#logging) and change its level or add a filter to it. No need to alter the source.